# Paste texture as background libgdx

Tags: java, opengl, libgdx, 2d

I'm trying to get a png file to be pasted onto the screen as a backdrop for my game, so far I can't seem to get this to work and I'm not too sure.

I have created a map class and have it create the Texture like so:

```
public static Texture backgroundTexture;
public static Sprite backgroundSprite;


public Maps(){
    try{
        backgroundTexture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("background.png"));
        backgroundSprite = new Sprite(backgroundTexture);
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void renderBackground(SpriteBatch batch){
    batch.draw(backgroundTexture, 1000, 800);
}
```

Then in my main class I have it called like so in the create method:

```
batch = new SpriteBatch();
map = new Maps();
    batch.begin();
    map.renderBackground(batch);
    batch.end();
```

But this doesn't work? Should it be in render method cos it needs to refresh the background each turn? I've tried it in render but still didn't work. My screen size is WXH 1000x800

Comment: This line's (`batch.draw(backgroundTexture, 1000, 800);`) arguments for X and Y are the position of the bottom left corner of the texture. I think you either want to use (0, 0) or (-screenWidth/2, -screenHeight/2), depending on how your camera is set up.

Comment: Are you not using a camera with your sprite batch? If you are not, it will treat the screen dimensions as if they are 2 x 2.

Comment: @noone That's OpenGL's default. If you do not transform vertex positions in the vertex shader (or if the transform matrix is identity as it is in SpriteBatch if left unchanged) everything is mapped to (-1, -1) to (1, 1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
OrthographicCamera cam = new OrthographicCamera(1000, 800);
SpriteBatch batch = new SpriteBatch();
Maps map = new Maps();
```

in your render/update method:

```
batch.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);
batch.begin();
map.renderBackground(batch);
batch.end();
```

in your Maps render method:

```
batch.draw(backgroundTexture, 0, 0, 1000, 800); //x, y, width, height
```

Comment: Great this worked, except I can't see all my graphics and stuff anymore. Is it pasting on top of that now?

Fixed, was because I should called it before draw player! This worked! Thanks heaps!